# Sweden tourist or visiting a friend visa

Tags: visas, schengen, sweden

I planning on going to Sweden and I am not sure which visa type should I apply to; tourist or visiting a friend.

I will be going to Stockholm and I will be meeting a friend, there we will go on the same day of arrival to Åre for skiing, we will be back to Stockholm after a couple of days where I will spend (one or max 2) days (either at his place or at a hotel) with my friend.

Then I will go to Italy for a couple more days.

Please note that my friend has just started working there for a couple of months.

Comment: Your travel pattern involves a combination of visiting a friend and tourism. You can use either however remember with a visit visa you typically need an invitation from the friend/family who is **legally** resident in the country in question. On the other hand a tourist visa typically only requires hotel proof of accommodation. Your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your travel pattern involves a combination of visiting a friend and tourism. You can use either however remember with a visit visa you typically need an invitation from the friend/family who is legally resident in the country in question.

On the other hand a tourist visa typically only requires hotel proof of accommodation. Your choice which to choose, or even both if the forms allow.